# Truncate table on cluster in Clickhouse

Tags: truncate, clickhouse

I am using Clickhouse version `20.1.5` and set up a cluster with a number of Clickhouse replicas. I also set `insert_quorum = 2`.

When I do `truncate table [table_name] on cluster [cluster_name]`, it completes normally. But when I execute this query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name`, I got this error

```
Code: 289. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Received from 10.33.179.126:9000. DB::Exception: Replica doesn't have part all_56_56_0 which was successfully written to quorum of other replicas. Send query to another replica or disable 'select_sequential_consistency' setting..
```

Do you know what is the reason and how can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at this [CH Issue 5326](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/5326).

Comment: I considered this as a bug in Clickhouse. I tried this query `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table_name` where ID is a non-null column and it works. Other queries without * also work, so I don't know why, for some reasons `COUNT(*)` doesn't work.

Comment: It would be good you add the comment to this [Issue](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/5326) to describe this behavior.

Comment: Maybe that is because I am running version `20.1`. I will upgrade to version `20.4` and try again.